# Generate Classes From HTML Documentation

Tags: c#, xslt, code-generation, t4

I have some third party web service documentation formatted into HTML tables like this (first line is the header):

```
ElementNum|ElementName|DataType|Length|DecimalPlaces|Description
0123456879|SomeElement|Alphanum|10    |0            |YourMotherTrebek
```

I need to generate request/response objects based on the rows in this table:

```
/// <summary>0123456789</summary>
public string SomeElement { get; set; }
```

The quick and dirty route involved me copying tables from a browser into a text editor and doing find/replaces, but that doesn't work so well when I get into method documentation where the request object has >300 input fields.

Is [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) or XSLT the way to go for something like this, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ask me to write it for you but you might consider XSLT. It is an incredibly powerful pattern-matching language for transforming XML into anything else.  You might at least try adding that as a tag to see if anyone has done something similar.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: Yeah, good suggestion. Someone else in the office suggested that, too, but I forgot all about it.

Comment: I think it is an answer he didn't ask how to do it in T4 he asked if there was an easier way and I think XSLT would be an easier way.